# Angular 6+ HostListener on numeric input side arrows selector?

Tags: html, angular, input, directive

I am facing an issue where I have a directive sitting on an input type=number, those with side arrows for selecting numbers up and down.

[image]

I am using HostListener but I can't find a way to target the specific event when the user clicks on the side arrows.

So far I have tried:

- `@HostListener(change')`: does not work at all
- `@HostListener('ngModelChange')`: cause an infinite loop when the user uses the keyboard after
- `@HostListener('click')`: It's the only one the works but the event does not contain the input value as it is a generic click event.
- `@HostListener('input')`: Only works when the users input a number using the keyboard

Does anyone know the official way of getting this event?

```js
 @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onEvent(event) {
    this._propagateTouch();
    this._propagateChange(event.target.value);
    // console.log('input');
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onChange(event) {
    this._propagateTouch();
    this._propagateChange(event);
    console.log('arrow change');
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event) {
    this._propagateTouch();
    this._propagateChange(event.target.value);
  }
```

Comment: click event gets the value when you click on the arrows

Comment: the click event on the spinners(arrows) is just a generic mouse event and does not contain "target.value" but you are right in the sense that somehow I am now getting the value in the parent component

Comment: Yes, click and input should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular executes provided /configured method for [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) when the element emits the configured event. There are two events `change` and `input` available for `input`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

For input when user click on side up or down arrow event get fired for `@HostListener("input", ["$event"])`. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-wtkyg5?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
  @HostListener("input", ["$event"])
    public onInput(event: any): void {
        console.log("input:"+ event);
        alert(event);
    }
```

---

```
 @HostListener("input", ["$event.target"])
    public onInput(event: any): void {
        console.log("input:"+ event);
        alert(event);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, somehow it is working now passing the entire mouse event object which does not contains "target.value", angular is able to get the input value. I do not understand how yet but i am investigating, i have a feeling that it has something to do with ContorlValueAccessor that i implement in the Directive.

Comment: Thank you nayakam for your help, unfortunatelly i am using a  UI library called NG-ZORRO that has a component called "input-number" that wraps around the input field, so @HostListener("input") does not work, only click. It took me a while to figure this out. But in the case of standard HTMl input your answer is perfectly fine.